# Correct way to set the --network=container:<my_container> parameter?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-container-os

What is the correct way in Google Container Optimised OS to do the equivalent of `--network=container:<my_container>` to route all traffic from one container to another? I'm attempting to route all traffic (or as a fallback just HTTP/HTTPS) to another container.

I'm unsure if there's a better way to achieve this than the following options i've some up with:

1. Running the `docker run ...` command manually inside the container
2. Using cloud-init to automatically run the `docker run ...` command with the network flag set
3. Runtime forwarding (HTTP) traffic to the second container using a proxy to fire over all connections

Each of these solutions comes with a bunch of additional problems, is there a better solution to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation in Github that suggests on creating [Traffic Director](https://gist.github.com/viglesiasce/46b3c30dbfdd392cf6e41c3472f656aa).